# Remove row duplicates and get the highest value with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group

With the following query

```sql
SELECT
  users.id,
  users.username,
  users.email,
  groups.permission
FROM users
INNER JOIN memberships ON users.id = memberships.user_id
INNER JOIN groups ON memberships.group_id = groups.id
INNER JOIN groupings ON groups.id = groupings.group_id
WHERE groupings.repo_id = 1
GROUP BY users.id, groups.permission
ORDER BY users.id
```

I get the following rows:

```
----+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------+------------
 id |         username          |                  email                  | permission 
----+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------+------------
  2 | viva_leuschke0            | viva_leuschke0@ritchiealtenwerth.org    | 1
  2 | viva_leuschke0            | viva_leuschke0@ritchiealtenwerth.org    | 2
  3 | loyce_herman1             | herman1.loyce@bednar.com                | 1
  3 | loyce_herman1             | herman1.loyce@bednar.com                | 3
  4 | verona_vandervort2        | verona.vandervort2@mante.biz            | 1
  4 | verona_vandervort2        | verona.vandervort2@mante.biz            | 2
  4 | verona_vandervort2        | verona.vandervort2@mante.biz            | 3
  5 | bruen3_ms_hans            | ms.bruen3.hans@bechtelar.net            | 1
  5 | bruen3_ms_hans            | ms.bruen3.hans@bechtelar.net            | 2
  5 | bruen3_ms_hans            | ms.bruen3.hans@bechtelar.net            | 3
----+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------+------------
```

The question is: how can I tweak this query to return unique rows, filtering by the highest permission value? Something like:

```
----+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------+------------
 id |         username          |                  email                  | permission 
----+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------+------------
  2 | viva_leuschke0            | viva_leuschke0@ritchiealtenwerth.org    | 2
  3 | loyce_herman1             | herman1.loyce@bednar.com                | 3
  4 | verona_vandervort2        | verona.vandervort2@mante.biz            | 3
  5 | bruen3_ms_hans            | ms.bruen3.hans@bechtelar.net            | 3
----+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------+------------
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1.

**UPDATE:** By using the `DISTINCT ON` clause I was able to get what I wanted.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(users.id)
  users.id,
  users.username,
  users.email,
  groups.permission
FROM users
INNER JOIN memberships ON users.id = memberships.user_id
INNER JOIN groups ON memberships.group_id = groups.id
INNER JOIN groupings ON groups.id = groupings.group_id
WHERE groupings.repo_id = 1
GROUP BY users.id, groups.permission
ORDER BY 
  users.id ASC, 
  groups.permission DESC
```

Is this the best way of doing it?

Comment: I suppose you post the (valid!) answer you found as *answer* and accept it. That's the recommended way: you can answer your own question.

Comment: Hehehehehe... actually, I was asking if the query was the best one to the job.

Comment: Seems like I missed two things. Your added question and the imperfection in your added query. Nice, clean question, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On closer inspection, your query can (and should) be improved:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (u.id)
      ,u.id
      ,u.username
      ,u.email
      ,g.permission
FROM   users       u
JOIN   memberships m  ON m.user_id = u.id
JOIN   groups      g  ON g.id = m.group_id
JOIN   groupings   gi ON gi.group_id = g.id 
WHERE  gi.repo_id = 1
GROUP  BY u.id, g.permission
ORDER  BY u.id, g.permission DESC
```

The `GROUP BY` is of no use. `DISTINCT ON` alone gives you a unique `users.id`. Remove the `GROUP BY`, you'll get the same result, just faster.

You may want to add more columns to `ORDER BY` to decide which row to pick where more than one per `id` share the highest `permission`. The way you have it, you get an arbitrary pick for this case (provided it can occur).

[My reference answer for this query technique has more explanation, a benchmark and links.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot for the link. It also includes info about how to add a proper index. <3 <3 <3